# Create List from Map with first N objects from Map values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Just got curious :)

I have a Map object `map`, and I can get a list of String objects (values from map) by using:

```
new ArrayList<Ad>(map.values());
```

Is there a way to get the FIRST N objects with values from map and form a new Array/Arraylist without iteration?

Good day,
James

Comment: (new ArrayList<Ad>(map.values())).subList(0, count-1);
isn't that bad.

Comment: You do realize that the order of values() is undefined, so you don't know *which* N objects you will get? And you need to decide whether the values are `Strings` or `Ads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.copyOf(map.values().toArray(), n)
```